# Is HTTP 301(URL Forwording) work for XMPP?

Tags: http, dns, xmpp

I've got some new domain for ejabberd. But the APP client has hard code of the old  domain. I think it'll be okay to set a 301 in Godaddy to the new domain, if there's only web request.

But I don't know whether it also work on XMPP. Although I know that XMPP is based on HTTP.

Can anybody helps me make sure of that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XMPP is **not** based on HTTP.

If you want to make sure people connect to a different server, but still use the same domain name, you can add SRV records that point to the new domain.

If you want people to connect to a different server and use a different domain, you'll have to change the clients' configuration, as XMPP doesn't have redirects like this.

Comment: Sorry, I've make such a mistake of XMPP on HTTP. It's only happens with BOSH.